# i usually get this error message: deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be float, object given

Tags: laravel

below is my code in my timeController. am trying to get the distance between two coordinates, given a set of longitudes and latitudes. however I get an error message when I load it in my browser, saying `deg2rad()` expects parameter 1 to be float, object given

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// require_once __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';

use DB;

class TimeController extends Controller
{
public function show()
{
    $mechanics =    DB::table('issues')->pluck('lat');
    $mechanic_long =    DB::table('issues')->where('location', 'Lagos,      Nigeria')->value('lng');
    $lat =    DB::table('mechanics')->where('state', 'Lagos, Nigeria')->value('lat');
    $long =    DB::table('mechanics')->where('state', 'Lagos, Nigeria')->value('lng');


    // $los_angeles =    DB::table('mechanics')->where('state', 'Lagos, Nigeria')->get();

    $theta = $mechanic_long - $long;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($mechanics)) * sin(deg2rad($lat)) +  cos(deg2rad($mechanics)) * cos(deg2rad($lat)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344;
```

please help. thanks

Comment: Hello! I think something with the code formatting went wrong, as the code doesn't compile. Could you fix the formatting and give valid code? Furthermore, the machine might be right: Is `$mechanics` really a float or some kind of table object?

Comment: Error message clearly says whats the problem. $mechanics is the object and method `deg2rad()` requires float. Please post your Table (Model) structure so that we can post answer for you.

Comment: <?php
class CreateIssuesTable extends Migration
{
       public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Issues', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('vname');
            $table->string('problem');
            $table->string('location');
           $table->double('lat',20,10);
           $table->double('lng',20,10);
           $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

      }

Answer (score 0):

The pluck function returns a collection and this is a object.

You should extract the correct value out of the object and insert that into the deg2rad function.

Comment: please how do I extract the correct value and insert it. thanks

Comment: That depends of what the content of your object is, you can dump the content of the object by doing ($mechanics), there are probably multiple objects here if you need the first do '$mechanic = $mechanics->first();' and then get the value you need with '$mechanic->your_value_here'. hope it helps.